# dbms_output cannot print boolean?

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean, database-cursor, dbms-output

I am learning cursors and I cannot print the boolean value in the

```
dbms_output.put_line();
```

The code is

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c_employees_3i is
SELECT * FROM employees_3i;
row_count BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
OPEN c_employees_3i;
row_count := c_employees_3i%isopen; 
Dbms_Output.put_line(bool_to_text(row_count));
CLOSE c_employees_3i;
END;
```

I get this error

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 22:
PLS-00201: identifier 'BOOL_TO_TEXT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please help me to rectify the error. Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The function `bool_to_text` does not exist (and AFAIK, Oracle never had such a function).

You can use `diutil.bool_to_int` to convert the Boolean to an Integer and print that:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(sys.diutil.bool_to_int(true));
end;
```

Comment: also when I try to use row count . It always returns 0 even if there are values in the table .DECLARE
CURSOR c_employees_3i is
SELECT * FROM employees_3i;
row_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
OPEN c_employees_3i;
row_count := c_employees_3i%rowcount; 
Dbms_Output.put_line(row_count);
CLOSE c_employees_3i;
END;

Comment: @ShreeNaath Please ask a separate question for this (after searching the site for similar questions. I'd guess this has been asked before).